# Symfony5 fixtures with order - getOrder() doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fixtures, symfony5

When I added new fixtures file

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
{
    // get user fixtures
    $user = $this->getReference(LoadUserData::USER_REFERENCE);
    $userSecond = $this->getReference(LoadUserData::USER_TWO_REFERENCE);

    $productFirst = Product::create($user, 'title1', 'title1', 'description3', null, null);
    $manager->persist($productFirst);

    $productSecond = Product::create($user, 'title2', 'title2', 'description2', null, null);
    $manager->persist($productSecond);

    $productThird = Product::create($userSecond, 'title3', 'title3', 'description3', null, null);
    $manager->persist($productThird);

    $manager->flush();
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getGroups(): array
{
    return ['demo', 'default'];
}
```

I caught error

> purging database

> loading DataFixtures\LoadUserData

> In ReferenceRepository.php line 154:

> Reference to "ROLE_USER" does not exist

Class LoadRoleData has method getOrder(), but it doesn't work.

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return 1; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
}
```

Earlier all were done.

> purging database

> loading DataFixtures\LoadRoleData

> loading DataFixtures\LoadUserData

> ...

UPDATE:
Class LoadUserData has

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
     public function getDependencies()
     {
        return [
            LoadRoleData::class
        ];
     }
```

But it doesn't work too ((

**How can I set order for Role Fixtures in Symfony5?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of you deciding on the order of inserting fixtures, you should let Symfony decide.

To do that, your fixture classes should implement `DependentFixtureInterface` and override method `getDependencies()`. In your case, it should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

class LoadUserData extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            LoadRoleData::class,
        ];
    }

}
```

Now, Symfony will know that it needs to insert LoadRoleData first.

Using `DependentFixtureInterface`, you should never worry about the order of inserting if you have set up dependencies correctly.

Comment: I use ```getDependencies({return [Load1RoleData::class];})``` in LoadUserData, but it doesn't work too ((
Any idea?

Comment: @ultimatum The code in the original post inserts Products and requires references from User fixtures. Have you also added `DependentFixtureInterface ` on your Product fixtures class and returned  `return [LoadUserData::class,];` in `getDependencies()` method?
As I said, when you reference data from another fixture class, you have use DependentFixtureInterface.

Comment: Yes, are you right, it was my mistake, I missed implementation DependentFixtureInterface.
@mpaden Thanks a lot!